# Authorization Error in Postman when connecting to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am trying to get Authorization code from Postman by sending the Post request to " [https://auth.excattargetapis.com/v1/requestToken]".

In the Body of the Postman I have clientId and clientSecret but  Authorisation comes with following error

```
"documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm",
"errorcode": 0,
"message": "Bad Request"
```

Comment: Could you add your call as well (masking the keys)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bad request usually means your call is malformed. 
I would recommend using this [Postman library](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman). It would store your  credentials as environment variables and then you dont have to worry about handling the token call; it would be templated.

Reference:

- [Marketing Cloud Postman Collection](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the [Marketing Cloud Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm) and follow the steps. If you are passing clientId and clientSecret as JSON String in the body, make sure you have selected JSON(application/json) in the dropdown.

**Example Request for Production**

```
POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "clientId": "gyjzvytv7ukqtfn3x2qdyfsn",
  "clientSecret": "************"
}
```

Postman screenshot

[image]

Comment: Here is a github group to follow: https://github.com/sfmcdg/awesome-salesforce-marketingcloud

Answer (score 0):

The call is probably not done correctly or the keys have changed. I recommend you to watch [this webinar](https://vimeo.com/232789197) by Eliot Harper.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. Old key wasn’t working so I created a new key instead.